# Можно ли получить относительный путь для изображения через $().attr()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование

Можно ли получить относительный путь для изображение через $().attr()?
Я понял, что метод .attr в моем случае возвращает абсолютный путь изображения, что для строки (*) не подходит. Как либо получить ровно то, что находится в атрибуте src изображения .hidden img (первое из них)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".next").click(function() {
    let s = $(".hidden > img").attr("src");
    console.log("s = ", s); //s =  file:// (*)  /C:/Users/User/Desktop/TheSite/imadges/gallery/image1.jpg
    //       а нужно /imadges/gallery/image1.jpg
    //       либо сделать так, чтобы то что возвращает s было валидно для рядка строки ниже

    $(".big-image img").attr("src", s); //(*)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery-box">
  <div class="view">
    <div class="big-image"><img src="imadges/gallery/image1.jpg" alt="image1"></div>
    <a href="#" class="next">next</a>
  </div>

  <div class="hidden" style="display: none;">
    <img src="imadges/gallery/image1.jpg" alt="image1">
    <img src="imadges/gallery/image2.jpeg" alt="image2">
    <img src="imadges/gallery/image3.jpeg" alt="image3">
    <img src="imadges/gallery/image4.jpg" alt="image4">
    <img src="imadges/gallery/image5.jpg" alt="image5">
  </div>
</div>
```

Да я сижу за этим целый день

Comment: Покажите ваш html

Comment: вставил мой html

Comment: Ваш кот отлично работает. Проверьте

Answer (score 1):

В чем вопрос? Все работает без всяких локальных путей

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".next").click(function() {
    let s = $(".hidden > img").attr("src"); 
    console.log("s = ", s);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden">
  <img src="/imadges/gallery/image1.jpg"/>
<div>
<button class="next">Next</button>
```